# ImportError when importing win32com.client in a subfolder

Tags: python, import, subdirectory, win32com

When I import the win32com.client such as this:

`import win32com.client as win3`

It works when my python file (test.py) is located in the src folder. (Eclipse PyDev)

But when I move the file into a subfolder src/subfolder/test.py then I get the error

`import win32com.client as win32
ImportError: No module named client`

the subfolder does have a __init__.py file in it and everything else seems to be working, until I try to import the win32com.client

**What could be the problem, how do i fix it?**

Comment: what is your subfolder called?

Comment: The subfolder is called "Excel", but renaming it sadly didn't change anything

Comment: if you print `sys.path` before the import what do you see?

Comment: win32 is part of it:
Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 
Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',